# Add Azure B2C tenant as an Identity Provider for Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0

I have an application connected to an Azure B2C tenant that hosts external customers and this B2C tenant has Azure AD as an identity provider.

Users see the B2C sign in page and a button to allow internal users to sign in with their existing Azure AD, so the main repo for users is B2C Tenant.

I want to flip it the other way around. Use Azure AD to authenticate app and add B2C tenant as an identity provider so external users can log in to the system.

I need this because we are facing a lot of issues with B2C including MFA enrollment and some other weird behaviors that my client isn't happy about.

What I did so far:

Create an enterprise app, got the metadata URL
Opened External Identities in Azure AD and tried to add a new New SAML/WS-Fed IdP, spicified the name, domain of my B2C tenant and choose to parse from the metadata file that I downloaded from the enterprise app on my B2C Tenant

[image]

When I click save, I get the following error

Invalid domain b2cdemotraining.onmicrosoft.com. Domain should match the passiveSignInUri. Otherwise, please add the passiveSignInUri in the domain DNS TXT record like this DirectFedAuthUrl=https://login.microsoftonline.com/[my tenant id]/saml2.

The B2C tenant has no custom domain name and I have no idea how to get passed this error !!

Can I actually use B2C as an identity provider for Azure AD? or this is not supported?

Created an enterprise app in B2C and tried to create an identity provider in Azure AD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note** that: Using B2B you can configure Google/Facebook as identity provider, but not B2C because B2C as IdP is not supported in Azure AD.  Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation)

[image]

Adding B2C as IdP is like multi-tenant scenario. **As a workaround**, if you want to use Azure AD application to authenticate the Azure AD B2C users then create a multi-tenant Azure AD application.

[image]

For ***sample***, I used the below endpoint to authenticate B2C users:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=user.read
&state=12345
```

[image]

The user successfully authenticated:

[image]

For configuring Azure AD as External Identity in Azure AD B2C refer [Set up sign-in for a Microsoft Entra organization - Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow)

Comment: I do not want to configure Azure AD as external identity in azure AD B2C,  I want to do the opposite but it seems that it is not possible

Comment: Afaik that is not possible as a workaround you can create multi tenant application